# Extract number from string pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string like this: `_999_123456_8888888-123564578`

From this I need to extract the data in the position i.e `123456` in the above pattern.

Underscores are fixed - just need the data between the second and third `_`

Comment: Describe why 123456 is supposed to be extracted. Always same format, i.e. number of dashes and digits?

Comment: Yes that is correct. digits can varies

Comment: Yes that is correct - between "999" and "_8888"

Comment: `After the second _ character and before the - character` this is `123456_8888888` in your example, not only `123456`

Comment: Is the three underscores are fixed or it can be increase or decrease ?

Comment: underscores are fixed - just need the data between the second and third _

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments the underscores are fixed and need the data between the second and third underscores, you can use  [`PARSENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms188006.aspx) to get your expected data.

Sample execution:

```
DECLARE @TestString AS VARCHAR (200) = '_999_123456_8888888-123564578'; 
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(@TestString, '_', '.'), 2)
```

Comment: That is perfect !

Answer (score 1):

This may helps you

```
Declare @Number Varchar(max)='_999_123456_8888888-123564578'
Declare @ExtractNumber Varchar(20)='123456' -- Give number your required without specialcharecters
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Number,CHARINDEX(@ExtractNumber,@Number),Len(@ExtractNumber))As ExtractedValue
```

OutPut

```
ExtractedValue
-------------
123456
```